# how to get database or container size in cosmosDB with query?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to retrieve the number of items in a container and the size of a container.
I can receive the number of items in a container with the below query.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM c
```

response:

```
[
    {
        "$1": 3
    }
]
```

Is there a query for receiving size?

Answer (score 1):

The information about the approximate size of the container and the number of items are exposed through `x-ms-resource-usage` response header when you execute a normal query like `Select * From Root`.

This is how you data looks like:

```
documentSize=0;documentsSize=107;documentsCount=30;collectionSize=114;
```

You can parse the response header and get the value. The size is returned in KB. So in the example above, the total size of the documents is 107KB and the total size of the collection is 114KB.

If you're using .Net SDK, you can get this information in [`ResourceResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.resourceresponse-1?view=azure-dotnet). The properties you would be interested in are [`DocumentUsage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.resourceresponsebase.documentusage?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_ResourceResponseBase_DocumentUsage). I have not looked in other SDKs but I am pretty sure that you will find something similar there.

There are some other ways to find this information as well. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db.